# Simpler way to get GitLab group access token info

Tags: gitlab

Given a GitLab group access token, is there a simple way to query the API to see properties of the token?   The Gitlab API has an [endpoint to get that info](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/group_access_tokens.html#get-a-group-access-token), but that requires knowing the token ID.

The way I've gotten to the information includes multiple steps, and I wonder whether there is a simpler way.  Currently I do:

1. Get the user info using that group access token to authenticate ([docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#single-user)). This gives me the user id
2. Get the list of groups using the token to authenticate ([docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#list-groups)). This gives me the top-level group that this token can access
3. Get the list of the group's tokens ([docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/group_access_tokens.html#list-group-access-tokens)). I can then filter that list to pick out the token data for the user whose id matches the id from step 1.  This is what I'm after.

```
    {
        "id": 123456,
        "name": "token-name",
        "revoked": false,
        "created_at": "2022-05-20...",
        "scopes": [
            "api"
        ],
        "user_id": 123456,
        "last_used_at": "2023-01-01...",
        "active": true,
        "expires_at": "2023-02-01",
        "access_level": 30
    }
```

Ideally, there would be a token introspection endpoint where I can see info about the token I'm presenting for authentication.  I tried the OAuth2 introspection endpoint (gitlab.com/oauth/userinfo) with the group access token but it returned 401 Unauthorized.